# Find name of element using wildcard

Tags: xml, t-sql, xquery, wildcard

I am trying to read an xml element name using TSQL using the wildcard character `*` but I can't quite get it to work: The below query returns blank trying to read an element called 'xs_address'

```
<TestXML>
<Properties />
  <Body>
    <xs_name Type="text" Value="John Smith" />
    <xs_address Type="text" Value="123 Fake Street" />
    </Body>
</TestXML>
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
     @x.value('local-name((/TestXML/Body/*:_address)[1])','VARCHAR(30)') AS ElementName
```

The element I need to read will sometimes have a different name before the underscore e.g. `dis_address`

How can i ensure I always read the correct element?

Comment: Please always provide example input, and the expected output. Read [ask] and [how to provide an SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: expected output is the element name 'xs_address'

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

```
DECLARE @x XML=N'<TestXML>
  <Properties />
  <Body>
    <xs_name Type="text" Value="John Smith" />
    <xs_address Type="text" Value="123 Fake Street">abc</xs_address>
  </Body>
</TestXML>'

SELECT ElementName FROM (
    SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','varchar(30)') AS ElementName 
    FROM @x.nodes('/TestXML/Body/*') T(c)
) q WHERE ElementName LIKE '%[_]address'

SELECT @x.value('local-name((/TestXML/Body/*)
[contains(local-name(),"_address")]
[1])','varchar(30)') AS ElementName 
    
SELECT @x.value('local-name((/TestXML/Body/*)
[substring(local-name(),string-length(local-name())-7,8)="_address"]
[1])','varchar(30)') AS ElementName
```

*Later edit:*

The three queries provide slightly different results in some circumstances:

- The first query extracts the names of all elements in /TestXML/Body, and then uses a WHERE condition to find the ones that end with "_address".
- The second query uses an X-Query condition to find the first element which has a name containing "_address".
- The third query uses an X-Query condition to find the first element which has a name that ends with "_address".

Comment: Please describe how this solves the problem. Just pasting a solution won't help anyone with a similar problem.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: is it ok now?

Comment: Yes, much better. Many readers would not have been able to infer your three bullet points from the code alone.